# Fast disk-based HashSet / Index for large set of Strings

Tags: c#, caching, indexing, hash, lucene.net

I'm looking for a solution on how to index a large set of strings - say 100 000 000 (probably more) with an average length of 50 bytes each (= 5 000 000 000 = 5 GB of data; and then in UTF16 and with .NET memory allocation, even more).

I then want to use the index to allow other processes to query if a string exists in the index -- and this as fast as possible.

I've done some simple testing with a large memory based HashSet - about 1 000 000 strings - and looking up e.g. 50 000 strings in that HashSet is only a matter of milliseconds.

Here's some pseudo code for what I want to achieve:

```
// 1) create huge disk based HashSet / Index / Lookup
using (var hs = DiskBasedHashSet<string>(@"c:\index.bin", .create)) {
    for each (var s in lotsOfStringsToIndex) {
        hs.Add(s);
    }
}

// 2) use index to check if items exists - this need to be fast
public static class Query {
    static var hs = DiskBasedHashSet<string>(@"c:\index.bin", .read);

    // callable from anywhere, and really fast
    public static QueryItem(string s) {
        return hs.Contains(s);
    }
}

for each (var s in checkForThese) {
    var result = Query.QueryItem(s); 
}
```

I've tried using SQL Servers, Lucene.NET, and B+Trees, with and without partitioning data. Anyhow, these solutions are to slow and, I think, overqualified for this task. Immagine, the overhead of creating a SQL-query or a Lucene Filter, just do check for a string in a set.

Comment: I think Trie could be really fast for what you need, smaller memory footprint and fast search - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it!

Comment: Not a complete answer but worth having a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter it's a very small data structure (somewhat like a HashSet) that can tell you it a value definite isn't or probably is in a set. The probability can be tuned)
There are many c# implementation like https://gist.github.com/richardkundl/8300092 searching google for "bloom filter c#" 
The idea being you check the BF first then a more expensive HashSet only if it returns true. This will work well depending on the hit rate your scenario expects

Comment: @FredrikJohansson I'd be very interested in something like this as well, but given there is no answer since 2016... I think you havent found anything